# Problem with shadow in Beamer's blocks, via dvips and ps2pdf

Tags: beamer, ghostscript

When I compile that code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[]{Madrid}
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Question 1 \hspace{3cm} Développement}
\begin{exampleblock}{Forme développée de }
\begin{center}
\bigskip
\huge
$(4x-8)(2x+3)$
\bigskip
\end{center}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

1/ with pdflatex, no problem

2/ with latex + dvips + ps2pdf, the shadow is incorrect (see the picture)

[image: shadow_problem]

It seems the problem is in GPL GhostScript. With GhostScript 9.21, I have no problem.
In TexLive, it's GhostScript 9.26 and, yes, there is a problem...

What can I do ?

Best regards

François

Comment: get another ghostscript.

Comment: I've exactly the same problem with GhostScript 9.53.3 and MikTeX 23.4. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx,  Since this question has remained unanswered for more than two years, it would probably be more effective to ask a new question.